# Issue in loading contactlist for android client

Tags: php, android, mysql

I have developed an android client similar to chat applications , the application displays the contact list of the user's who are using the same app.

The issues is in loading the contact list which is too slow. This is the main page of my application.

I have used Aysnc task and running the heavy operations at the background (running only UI related tasks in the main thread) also using HTTP requests to perform tasks related to server using **GET** and **POST**.

I have used **php** and **mysql** for my server integration. Please help me find the solution for what might be the reason in delay of loading the contacts into my client app.

Kindly respond.

Comment: AsyncTask isnt the right one for the job, because it runs not every time at the time you started it. That's why it is called asynctask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Thread` should do it for you.
This could look like this:

```
    public void somemethod(){
     Thread t = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                doyourTask();
            }
        };
        t.start();
}
```

[Further solutions](http://developer.android.com/guide/faq/commontasks.html#threading)

Comment: I am running only the UI operations on the main thread. Hence the problem exists.

Comment: Checking thoroughly , i wont find any issues from client app. Is there anything i need to work on server side to improve the response time?

Comment: Some code of the server might help to find that out.

Comment: please chk the below client code , where m using Async task & main thread initially

Answer (score 0):

```
    package com.dextrols.bol_messanger.fragments;

import static com.dextrols.bol_messanger.pushnotifications.CommonUtilities.DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION;
import static com.dextrols.bol_messanger.pushnotifications.CommonUtilities.EXTRA_MOBILE_NUMBER;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.provider.Contacts.People;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.PhoneLookup;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.AbsListView.OnScrollListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.dextrols.bol_messanger.fragments.Profile_Settings_Child_Fragment.Load_All;
import com.dextrols.bol_messanger.invite_utils.Invite_Activity;
import com.dextrols.bol_messanger.pushnotifications.AlertDialogManager;
import com.dextrols.bol_messanger.pushnotifications.ConnectionDetector;
import com.dextrols.bol_messanger.pushnotifications.JSONParser;
import com.dextrols.bol_messanger.pushnotifications.R;
import com.dextrols.bol_messanger.pushnotifications.WakeLocker;
import com.dextrols.bol_messanger.utils.Database_Handler_Number;
import com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar;

public class Contacts_Fragment extends Activity implements OnScrollListener {

    ProgressDialog pDialog;

    String mPhoto_Uri,mName,mphoneNumber,audio_url_chat = "";

    ArrayList<String>Chat_List_Array = new ArrayList<String>();

    Database_Handler_Number mDatabase_Number;

    public static String Mobile_Number_Db="",country_db="",gcm_id_db="";

    String mDb_Numbers;

    ArrayList<String> mDb_Numbers_Array = new ArrayList<String>();

    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    String url = "*url_link_here*";

    JSONArray products = null,products1 = null;;

    String m_mobile_number;

    ListView lv;

    TextView no_contacts_text;

    HashMap<String, String> map_app_contacts;

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> m_hash_list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

    private static String url_chat_list_single = "*url_here*";

    public static String ID = "name";

    public static String NUMBER = "mobile_number";

    public static String IMAGE = "profile_image";

    public static String GCM_ID = "gcm_regid";

    public static String NAME = "name";

    public static String Audio = "audio_url";

    private ArrayList<String> mContacts_Array = new ArrayList<String>();

    private ArrayList<String> mNumbers = new ArrayList<String>();

    public static ArrayList<String> mChat_Array = new ArrayList<String>();

    String [] web_voice;

    private static final String TAG = "success";

    String audio_url_recive="",mContact_Number="";

    int success ;

    int size_chat;

    String count;

    int digits = 10;

    //  ImageView mAdd_Contact; 

    String [] mContact_Names;
    String [] mContact_Numbers;
    String [] mContact_Images;
    String [] mContact_GcmId;
    String [] mMessage_Count;

    ArrayList<String> mContacts_Names_Array = new ArrayList<String>();

    ArrayList<String> mContacts_Numbers_Array = new ArrayList<String>();

    ArrayList<String> mContacts_Images_Array = new ArrayList<String>();

    public static ArrayList<String> mContacts_Gcmid_Array = new ArrayList<String>();

    RelativeLayout screen;

    private ActionBar actionBar;

    CustomListAdapter adapter;

    TextView mConnection_Note;

    String mNotification_Number="";

    AlertDialogManager alert =  new AlertDialogManager();
    ConnectionDetector cd;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_contacts);

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
        .permitAll().build();

        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        actionBar = getActionBar();

        // Hide the action bar title
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());

        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#ef343e")));

        mDatabase_Number = new Database_Handler_Number(Contacts_Fragment.this);

        mDatabase_Number.open();

        Cursor getdetails=mDatabase_Number.getlistitems();

        if(getdetails.getCount()>0){

            if(getdetails.moveToFirst())

            {
                do{
                    Mobile_Number_Db = getdetails.getString(1);
                    Log.d("Db Mobile Number",""+Mobile_Number_Db);

                    country_db = getdetails.getString(2);
                    Log.d("Db Country",""+country_db);

                    gcm_id_db = getdetails.getString(3);
                    Log.d("Db GCM ID",""+gcm_id_db);

                }while(getdetails.moveToNext());
            }


        }else{

        }

        mDatabase_Number.close();

        mContacts_Array.clear();

        mNumbers.clear();

        mChat_Array.clear();

        getNumber(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver());

        mConnection_Note = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.connection_note);

        Internetchecker();

        if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {

        } else {

            new Load_All_Numbers().execute();
        }

        lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.contacts_list);
        screen = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.contact_screen);


        no_contacts_text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.no_contact_text);




        registerReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter(DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION));
    }

    /**
     * Receiving push messages
     * */
    private final BroadcastReceiver mHandleMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            // Waking up mobile if it is sleeping
            WakeLocker.acquire(Contacts_Fragment.this); 

            mNotification_Number = intent.getExtras().getString(EXTRA_MOBILE_NUMBER);
            mNotification_Number = mNotification_Number.replace("[", "");
            mNotification_Number = mNotification_Number.replace("]", "");
            mNotification_Number = mNotification_Number.replace("\"", "");
            Log.d("Number",""+mNotification_Number);

            String mContact_Save = getContactName(context, mNotification_Number);

            if (mContact_Save != null && !mContact_Save.isEmpty()) {

                mContacts_Array.clear();

                mNumbers.clear();

                mChat_Array.clear();

                Chat_List_Array.clear();

                getNumber(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver());

                new Load_All_Numbers().execute();

            } else {

                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Contacts_Fragment.this/*,android.R.style.Theme_Translucent*/);
                dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.new_contact_save);

                dialog.show();

                final EditText mContact_Name = (EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.new_contact_name);
                final TextView mContact_Submit = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.new_contact_submit);

                mContact_Submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        if (mContact_Name.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {

                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Required fields missing..!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



                        } else {

                            dialog.dismiss();

                            createContact(mContact_Name.getText().toString(), mNotification_Number);

                            mContacts_Array.clear();

                            mNumbers.clear();

                            mChat_Array.clear();

                            Chat_List_Array.clear();

                            getNumber(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver());

                            new Load_All_Numbers().execute();
                        }

                    }
                });
            }

            // Releasing wake lock
            WakeLocker.release();
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        try {

            unregisterReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver);

            GCMRegistrar.onDestroy(getApplicationContext());

        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.e("UnRegister Receiver Error", "> " + e.getMessage());
        }

        super.onDestroy();
    }




    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
            int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    private void getNumber(ContentResolver cr) {

        Cursor phones = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null,  Phone.DISPLAY_NAME+ " ASC");
        while (phones.moveToNext())
        {
            mName=phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
            System.out.println("................."+mName);


            mphoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            System.out.println(".................."+mphoneNumber);

            mphoneNumber = mphoneNumber.replaceAll("^0+", "");
            Log.i("Zero",""+mphoneNumber);

            mphoneNumber = mphoneNumber.replaceAll(" ", "").replace("(","").replace(")", "").replace("-", "").replace("+91", "");
            Log.d("Replaced Braces",""+mphoneNumber);


            mContacts_Array.add(mphoneNumber);


        }
        phones.close();// close cursor

    }

    class Load_All_Numbers extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url, "GET", params);


            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt("success");

                if (success == 1) {
                    // products found
                    // Getting Array of Products
                    products = json.getJSONArray("data");

                    // looping through All Products
                    for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {

                        JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                        m_mobile_number = c.getString("mobile_number");

                        mNumbers.add(m_mobile_number);

                    }
                } else {

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            mContacts_Names_Array.clear();

            mContacts_Images_Array.clear();

            mContacts_Gcmid_Array.clear();

            mContacts_Numbers_Array.clear();

            List<String> intersection = new ArrayList(mContacts_Array);
            intersection.retainAll(mNumbers);

            if (intersection.size()>0) {

                new Get_Chat().execute();

                new Get_Each_Contacts().execute();

                no_contacts_text.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            } else {

                no_contacts_text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }


        }

    }

    class Get_Chat extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {


            List<String> intersection = new ArrayList(mContacts_Array);
            intersection.retainAll(mNumbers);

            for ( String key_chat : intersection){

                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("from_number", key_chat));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("to_number", Mobile_Number_Db));

                JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_chat_list_single, "GET", params);

                try {

                    size_chat = json.getInt("size");

                    count = Integer.toString(size_chat);

                    Chat_List_Array.add(count);

                    Log.d("Size Array",""+Chat_List_Array);



                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
            return null;
        }


    }

    class Get_Each_Contacts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            try {

                List<String> union = new ArrayList(mContacts_Array);
                union.addAll(mNumbers);

                List<String> intersection = new ArrayList(mContacts_Array);
                intersection.retainAll(mNumbers);

                List<String> symmetricDifference = new ArrayList(union);
                symmetricDifference.removeAll(intersection);    

                for ( String key : intersection){

                    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mobile_number", key));

                    JSONObject jobj = jParser.makeHttpRequest("http://bolmessenger.com/voice_droid/single_user.php", "GET", params);

                    try {
                        // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                        int success = jobj.getInt("success");

                        if (success == 1) {
                            // products found
                            // Getting Array of Products
                            products1 = jobj.getJSONArray("single_login");

                            for (int i = 0; i < products1.length(); i++) {

                                JSONObject j = products1.getJSONObject(i);

                                mContacts_Names_Array.add(getContactName(getApplicationContext(), key));

                                mContacts_Numbers_Array.add(j.getString("mobile_number"));

                                mContacts_Images_Array.add(j.getString("profile_image"));

                                mContacts_Gcmid_Array.add(j.getString("gcm_regid"));

                                mContact_Names = new String [mContacts_Names_Array.size()];

                                for (int k = 0; k < mContacts_Names_Array.size(); k++) {

                                    mContact_Names[k] = mContacts_Names_Array.get(k);

                                }

                                mContact_Numbers = new String [mContacts_Numbers_Array.size()];

                                for (int k = 0; k < mContacts_Numbers_Array.size(); k++) {

                                    mContact_Numbers[k] = mContacts_Numbers_Array.get(k);
                                }

                                mContact_Images = new String [mContacts_Images_Array.size()];

                                for (int k = 0; k < mContacts_Images_Array.size(); k++) {

                                    mContact_Images[k] = mContacts_Images_Array.get(k);

                                }


                                mContact_GcmId = new String [mContacts_Gcmid_Array.size()];

                                for (int k = 0; k < mContacts_Gcmid_Array.size(); k++) {

                                    mContact_GcmId[k] = mContacts_Gcmid_Array.get(k);
                                }
                            }
                        } 

                        else {

                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                }


            } catch (Exception e){

                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            super.onPostExecute(result);

            adapter=new CustomListAdapter(Contacts_Fragment.this, mContact_Names, mContact_Numbers, mContact_Images, mContact_GcmId, Chat_List_Array);

            lv.setAdapter(adapter);

            /*lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {

                    Intent single_chat = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Single_Chat.class);
                    single_chat.putExtra("Mobile_Number", mContact_Numbers[position].toString());
                    startActivity(single_chat);
                    //  Toast.makeText(getActivity(), mContact_Names[position].toString() +"\n"+mContact_Numbers[position].toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });*/

        }


    }

    public String getContactName(Context context, String phoneNumber) {
        ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
        Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phoneNumber));
        Cursor cursor = cr.query(uri, new String[]{PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME}, null, null, null);
        if (cursor == null) {
            return null;
        }
        String contactName = null;
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            contactName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME));
        }

        if(cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
            cursor.close();
        }

        return contactName;
    }


    private void createContact(String name, String phone) {

        ContentValues contact = new ContentValues();

        contact.put(People.NAME, name);

        Uri insertUri = getContentResolver().insert(People.CONTENT_URI, contact);

        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(),insertUri.toString());

        Uri phoneUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(insertUri, People.Phones.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);

        contact.clear();

        contact.put(People.Phones.TYPE, People.TYPE_MOBILE);

        contact.put(People.NUMBER, phone);

        Uri updateUri = getContentResolver().insert(phoneUri, contact);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Created a new contact: " + name + " " + phone, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(),updateUri.toString());
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);

        /*// Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search)
                .getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager
                .getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));*/

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Take appropriate action for each action item click
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_settings:

            Intent mInvite = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Invite_Activity.class);
            mInvite.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(mInvite);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.push_down_in, R.anim.push_down_out);

            break;

        case R.id.profile_settings:

            Intent mProfile_Settings = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Profile_Settings_Child_Fragment.class);
            mProfile_Settings.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(mProfile_Settings);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.push_down_in, R.anim.push_down_out);

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.exit(0);

        super.onBackPressed();
    }

    private void Internetchecker() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        android.net.NetworkInfo wifi = cm
                .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
        android.net.NetworkInfo datac = cm
                .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
        if ((wifi != null & datac != null)
                && (wifi.isConnected() | datac.isConnected())) {
            //connection is avlilable
            //onResume();
            mConnection_Note.setEnabled(false);
            mConnection_Note.setVisibility(View.GONE);



        }else{
            //no connection
            mConnection_Note.setText("No Internet connection");
            mConnection_Note.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "no internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {

        Internetchecker();

        super.onResume();
    }



}
```

Comment: you should add this as an edit to your question, not as an answer

Comment: ok. sure will look forth hence while posting / adding on my questions